# Why isn't my audio player visible, and how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I made a playlist of songs with my `<a>` tags, and i made a ***player***, so when i click the item from list the player plays the song, but i can't see the player and control it, how can this be fixed, so i can see the player and still choose the song from the list? *(I did not style the audio player...)*

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<audio preload="auto" src="#" autoplay="true"></audio>

<a class="trigger" href="#" data-src="audio/song1.mp3">Song #1</a>
<a class="trigger" href="#" data-src="audio/song2.mp3">Song #2</a>
<a class="trigger" href="#" data-src="audio/song3.mp3">Song #3</a>
<a class="trigger" href="#" data-src="audio/song4.mp3">Song #4</a>
```

And the **JQUERY** i used for changing the source from audio tag

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function () {
    $('audio').prop('src', $(this).data('src'));
});
```

Comment: You forgot to add controls attribute to audio html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this :

```
<audio preload="auto" src="#" autoplay="true" controls></audio>
```